# Confusing relay rating

Tags: voltage, relay, amperage

I have this relay and the ratings are quite confusing - 10A 30v and 10A 28v, I'm confused as to why there are two. Could anyone please explain it to me.

Thank you

Comment: Do you have a part number or datasheet ?

Comment: Are you sure you haven't made a mistake transcribing the ratings?

Answer (score 3):

You're missing the symbols in front that tell you whether the rating is AC or DC. DC voltage ratings for electromechanical devices are much lower than their AC voltage ratings because lack of a zero crossing means that DC arcs do not self-extinguish.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes the ratings match regulatory requirements.  CSA/UL (North American) regulations may require different ratings than Euopean rules.

If the ratings you mention are both DC, I'd expect it is due to regulatory requirements - any UL or CE symbols beside those ratings?